# Javascript implementation of Twig style templates in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twig

I have used Backbone's underscore template, Mustache templates an d Jquery templates before in Backbone apps however I am building a framework whereby PHP and Javascript are both using the same template and have decided to go for the [Twig template format](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Everything works fine in PHP however I've now come to the JS and have found a [handful](https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js/) of [different](http://jmsyst.com/libs/twig.js) Twig libraries for javascript.

I am wondering if anyone has ever integrated twig templates with a backbone app and could save me a lot of time with suggesting which lib they used.

Thanks very much.